# jekyll yaml code not showing in markdown file

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am writing a docs markdown file for a website that I'm working on.  In the markdown, I tried to include this jekyll code:
    
    `{% assign features = site.work | where:"featured", "yes" | sort:"featured-rank" %}`

But once I load the docs.md file, there is no text to show. I know this is simple, can't figure it out.
I'm using the ``` ticks before the code and afterwards as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you need to display liquid code in a liquid (Jekyll) template. If so, you need to wrap your code in a `{% raw %}` tag like this:

````
```

{% raw %}
{% assign features = site.work | where:"featured", "yes" | sort:"featured-rank" %}
{% endraw %}

```
````

This prevents it being parsed by liquid.

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

You're only `assign`ing data to a variable (`features`) here. To output data, loop through the variable and extract info.
for example, assuming each item within has a variable `title` defined, to display the titles of the feature-items as a list.

```
<ul>
  {% for feature in features %}
    <li>{{ feature.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @ashmaroli but I understand how to use the assign variable, just needed to figure out how to show the assign code in my docs file using markdown.